# Upload a file in Swagger and receive at Flask backend

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I'm trying to upload a file using Swagger and Flask. I've the following configuration for swagger.

```
"/user/register/": {
    "post": {
        "tags": ["user"],
        "summary": "Register a new user",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "registerUser",
        "consumes": ["application/json"],
        "produces": ["application/json"],
        "parameters": [{
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "User object that needs to be added.",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "file",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "file to upload",
            "required": true,
            "type": "file"
        }]
    }
},
```

I do get the option for uploading a file, but when I try to receive it at the backend,(using `print request.files`) it returns me nothing.

How can I receive the file (selected at swagger level) at the backend.??

Answer (score 2):

`iFile = request.files.getlist('file')[0]`- This command reads the file uploaded via swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

For `file`, the type should be `formData` instead of `path`. See below for an example

```
      {
        "name": "file",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "file to upload",
        "required": false,
        "type": "file"
      }
```

ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json#L384

For `consumes`, it should be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I'm able to get the file uploaded as well, but now I'm not able to receive the above body data. How can I make it compatible? Earlier I was using `request.get_json()` which use to fetch me the json data. Now it no longer is of type `application/json`, hence I'm not able to fetch the data. How can I receive the upper body??

Comment: For `produces`, it should be `application/json` if the upload process returns JSON data.