# Handling Images in API with Python Flask/Connexion and Swagger

Tags: python, image, sqlite, flask, swagger-ui

I tried to setup a very simple app. I wanted to create this app as fullstack app as training for future projects. So i wrote a backend in python which provides data from a DB (SQLLite) via an API (Flask/Connexion). The API is documented via Swagger. The DB should have a table where each row got 2 values: 
1. name
2. images
I quickly faced a problem: I actually don't know how to handle images in APIs. Therefore I created the backup with a placeholder. Till now images is just another string which is mostly empty. Everything works fine. But now I want to be able to get Images via API and save them in the DB. I have absolutly no Idea how to do this. Hope one of you can help me.

Here is my Code so far:

**SqlliteHandler.py**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('sprint_name.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def connect_db():
    global conn
    global c
    conn = sqlite3.connect('sprint_name.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists sprint_names ( name text, image text)")


def make_db_call(execute_statement, fetch_smth=""):
    global c
    connect_db()
    print(execute_statement)
    c.execute(execute_statement)
    response = ""
    if fetch_smth is "one":
        response = transform_tuple_to_dict(c.fetchone())
    if fetch_smth is "all":
        response_as_tuples = c.fetchall()
        response = []
        for sug in response_as_tuples:
            response.append(transform_tuple_to_dict(sug))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return response


def transform_tuple_to_dict(my_tuple):
    return {"name": my_tuple[0], "image": my_tuple[1]}


def add_name(suggestion):
    name = suggestion.get("name")
    image = "" if suggestion.get("image") is None else suggestion.get("image")
    execute_statement = "SELECT * FROM sprint_names WHERE name='" + name + "'"
    print(execute_statement)
    alreadyexists = False if make_db_call(execute_statement, "one") is None else True
    print(alreadyexists)
    if not alreadyexists:
        execute_statement = "INSERT INTO sprint_names VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + image + "')"
        make_db_call(execute_statement)


def delete_name(suggestion_name):
    execute_statement = "DELETE FROM sprint_names WHERE name='" + suggestion_name + "'"
    print(execute_statement)
    make_db_call(execute_statement)


def delete_all():
    make_db_call("DELETE FROM sprint_names")


def get_all_names():
    return make_db_call("SELECT * FROM sprint_names", "all")


def get_name(suggestion_name):
    print(suggestion_name)
    execute_statement = "SELECT * FROM sprint_names WHERE name='" + suggestion_name + "'"
    print(execute_statement)
    return make_db_call(execute_statement, "one")


def update_image(suggestion_name, suggestion):
    new_name = suggestion.get("name" )
    new_image = "" if suggestion.get("image") is None else suggestion.get("image")
    execute_statement = "UPDATE sprint_names SET name='" + new_name + "', image='" + new_image + "' WHERE name='"\
                        + suggestion_name + "'"
    make_db_call(execute_statement)
```

**RunBackEnd.py**

```
from flask import render_template
import connexion

# Create the application instance
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./')
# Read the swagger.yml file to configure the endpoints
app.add_api('swagger.yml')

# Create a URL route in our application for "/"
@app.route('/')
def home():
    """
    This function just responds to the browser ULR
    localhost:5000/
    :return:        the rendered template 'home.html'
    """
    return render_template('home.html')

# If we're running in stand alone mode, run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

**Swagger.yml**

```
    swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: This is the swagger file that goes with our server code
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Swagger REST Article
consumes:
  - "application/json"
produces:
  - "application/json"

basePath: "/api"

# Paths supported by the server application
paths:
  /suggestions:
    get:
      operationId: SqlliteHandler.get_all_names
      tags:
        - suggestions
      summary: The names data structure supported by the server application
      description: Read the list of names
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful read names list operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              properties:
                name:
                  type: string
                image:
                  type: string
    post:
      operationId: SqlliteHandler.add_name
      tags:
        - suggestions
      summary: Create a name and add it to the names list
      description: Create a new name in the names list
      parameters:
        - name: suggestion
          in: body
          description: Suggestion you want to add to the sprint
          required: True
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
                description: Name you want to submit
              image:
                type: string
                description: path to the picture of that name
      responses:
        201:
          description: Successfully created name in list

  /suggestions/{suggestion_name}:
    get:
      operationId: SqlliteHandler.get_name
      tags:
        - suggestions
      summary: Read one name from the names list
      description: Read one name from the names list
      parameters:
        - name: suggestion_name
          in: path
          description: name of the sprint name to get from the list
          type: string
          required: True
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully read name from names list operation
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              image:
                type: string

    put:
      operationId: SqlliteHandler.update_image
      tags:
        - suggestions
      summary: Update an image in the suggestion list via the name of the suggestions
      description: Update an image in the suggestion list
      parameters:
        - name: suggestion_name
          in: path
          description: Suggestion you want to edit
          type: string
          required: True
        - name: suggestion
          in: body
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              image:
                type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully updated suggestion in suggestion list

    delete:
      operationId: SqlliteHandler.delete_name
      tags:
        - suggestions
      summary: Delete a suggestion via its name from the suggestion list
      description: Delete a suggestion
      parameters:
        - name: suggestion_name
          in: path
          type: string
          required: True
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully deleted a suggestion from the list
```

Comment: You can handle the images in lots of different ways - how would you *like* to? application/octet-stream? base64? even serialized numpy array..? How are you hitting the endpoint, and do you have a sample image? You can save them safely in your DB as base64 strings

Answer (score 1):

To save an image in SQLITE (***not that it's recommended, better to save the image as a file and to save the path in the DB***) you save it as an array of bytes (storage type of BLOB, not that the column has to be defined as a BLOB).

In SQL you specify an array of bytes as a hex string. So you read you image and build a hex string

- Noting

  - > Maximum length of a string or BLOB
    >
    > The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined
    >   by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this
    >   macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can
    >   raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option
    >   like this:
    >
    > -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789 The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647. And some
    >   built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In
    >   security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the
    >   maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower
    >   the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a
    >   few million if that is possible.
    >
    > During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete
    >   content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So
    >   the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of
    >   bytes in a row.
    >
    > The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the
    >   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

Also

- Noting

  - > Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement
    >
    > The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited
    >   to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1000000. You can redefine
    >   this limit to be as large as the smaller of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH and
    >   1073741824.
    >
    > If an SQL statement is limited to be a million bytes in length, then
    >   obviously you will not be able to insert multi-million byte strings by
    >   embedding them as literals inside of INSERT statements. But you should
    >   not do that anyway. Use host parameters for your data. Prepare short
    >   SQL statements like this:
    >
    > INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(?,?,?); Then use the sqlite3_bind_XXXX()
    >   functions to bind your large string values to the SQL statement. The
    >   use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the
    >   string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is also runs
    >   faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as
    >   much.
    >
    > The maximum length of an SQL statement can be lowered at run-time
    >   using the sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH,size) interface.

The resultant SQL would be along the lines of :-

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myimage) VALUES (x'fffe004577aabbcc33f1f8');
```

As a demo using your table (slightly modified to include the *"correct"* column type BLOB, which makes little difference) :-

```
DROP TABLE If EXISTS sprint_names;
CREATE TABLE if not exists sprint_names ( name text, image text, altimage BLOB);
INSERT INTO sprint_names VALUES
    ('SPRINT001',x'fffe004577aabbcc33f1f8',x'fffe004577aabbcc33f1f8'), -- obviously image would be larger
    ('SPRINT002',x'99008877665544332211f4d6e9c2aaa8b7b4',x'99008877665544332211f4d6e9c2aaa8b7b4')
;
SELECT * FROM sprint_names;
```

The result would be :-

[image]

- Note Navicat was used to run text the above. Blobs are inherently difficult to display hence display. However, what is shown is that the above obviously stores and retrieves the data.

As previously stated it's much simpler to just store the path to the image file and when it boils down to it there is likely very little need for the image as data. You're unlikely to be querying the data that the image is comprised of, whilst using naming standards could allow useful searches/queries of a stored name/path.

However, in contradiction of the above, SQLite can, in some circumstances (images with an average size around 100k or less (maybe more)) allow faster access than the file system [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Saving the path in the DB was my first ID, which is why image is of type string :D So I think I have to define an Upload Folder in my RunBackEnd.py, where all the uploaded images are stored. But how can I upload them via an API?

Comment: @itskajo Sorry I can't help in that area, I've never used Pyhton, let alone Flask or Swagger-ui. I'd guess that there would be tutorials around, perhaps [Upload a file in Swagger and receive at Flask backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495543/upload-a-file-in-swagger-and-receive-at-flask-backend) could assist.